After update react-native to 0.75.1 - react-native-fast-image gives error while running app on android
I have updated react-native to the latest 0.75.1 version and now have got the below error after running the application on Android.

node_modules/react-native-fast-image/android/src/main/java/com/dylanvann/fastimage/FastImageSource.java:14:
error: cannot inherit from final ImageSource public class
FastImageSource extends ImageSource {

Below are the versions used in the application
 "react": "18.3.1",
 "react-native": "0.75.1",
 "react-native-fast-image": "^8.6.3",


I faced same issue and got fixed by patching package in RN 75+
we need to edit FastImageSource.java file in
react-native-fast-image/android/src/main/java/com/dylanvann/fastimage/FastImageSource.java
and then need to patch package using patch-package
public class FastImageSource {
private final ImageSource imageSource;
private static final String DATA_SCHEME = "data";
private static final String LOCAL_RESOURCE_SCHEME = "res";
private static final String ANDROID_RESOURCE_SCHEME = "android.resource";
private static final String ANDROID_CONTENT_SCHEME = "content";
private static final String LOCAL_FILE_SCHEME = "file";
private final Headers mHeaders;
private Uri mUri;

public static boolean isBase64Uri(Uri uri) {
    return DATA_SCHEME.equals(uri.getScheme());
}

public static boolean isLocalResourceUri(Uri uri) {
    return LOCAL_RESOURCE_SCHEME.equals(uri.getScheme());
}

public static boolean isResourceUri(Uri uri) {
    return ANDROID_RESOURCE_SCHEME.equals(uri.getScheme());
}

public String getSource() {
    return imageSource.getSource();
}

public static boolean isContentUri(Uri uri) {
    return ANDROID_CONTENT_SCHEME.equals(uri.getScheme());
}

public static boolean isLocalFileUri(Uri uri) {
    return LOCAL_FILE_SCHEME.equals(uri.getScheme());
}

public FastImageSource(Context context, String source) {
    this(context, source, null);
}

public FastImageSource(Context context, String source, @Nullable Headers headers) {
    this(context, source, 0.0d, 0.0d, headers);
}

public FastImageSource(Context context, String source, double width, double height, @Nullable Headers headers) {
    imageSource = new ImageSource(context, source, width, height);
    mHeaders = headers == null ? Headers.DEFAULT : headers;
    mUri = imageSource.getUri();

    if (isResource() && TextUtils.isEmpty(mUri.toString())) {
        throw new Resources.NotFoundException("Local Resource Not Found. Resource: '" + imageSource + "'.");
    }

    if (isLocalResourceUri(mUri)) {
        // Convert res:/ scheme to android.resource:// so
        // glide can understand the uri.
        mUri = Uri.parse(mUri.toString().replace("res:/", ANDROID_RESOURCE_SCHEME + "://" + context.getPackageName() + "/"));
    }
}


public boolean isBase64Resource() {
    return mUri != null && FastImageSource.isBase64Uri(mUri);
}

public boolean isResource() {
    return mUri != null && FastImageSource.isResourceUri(mUri);
}

public boolean isLocalFile() {
    return mUri != null && FastImageSource.isLocalFileUri(mUri);
}

public boolean isContentUri() {
    return mUri != null && FastImageSource.isContentUri(mUri);
}

public Object getSourceForLoad() {
    if (isContentUri()) {
        return getSource();
    }
    if (isBase64Resource()) {
        return getSource();
    }
    if (isResource()) {
        return getUri();
    }
    if (isLocalFile()) {
        return getUri().toString();
    }
    return getGlideUrl();
}

public Uri getUri() {
    return mUri;
}

public Headers getHeaders() {
    return mHeaders;
}

public GlideUrl getGlideUrl() {
    return new GlideUrl(getUri().toString(), getHeaders());
}
 }

There is some changes,

removed extend class
added ImageSource variable to save ImageSource without extend class
super to ImageSource setter
remove override on getURI // NO MORE NEEDED because extend is removed
added getSource to export custom ImageSource to outside of class

tested and working on production build without any problem for two weeks to now

It worked !!! but you should give more details about how and where to do the changes, most of people will be confused abou what need to be done.

hello, yes you are right, thanks for you advice, I will edit answer
